# Event Grid not sending IoT Hub connection/disconnection events to Storage Queue

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I've tried connecting a certain IoT Hub's connection/disconnection events to a Storage Queue using the IoT Hub -> Events -> + Event Subscription, but no events or errors are ever received. The Events blade shows neither events nor errors. An Event Hub which receives these events via Diagnostics is working correctly, and I have checked that Event Grid subscription also doesn't work when Diagnostics is disabled.

I have tried two different IoT Hubs with the same and different Queue Storage and these both worked, so I suspect there is something funny about the specific IoT Hub I'm trying to set up, or some interaction with other settings which is breaking Event Grid. Is there any debugging or logging which could shed any light on this problem?

Comment: for test purpose: create an EventGridTrigger function and subscribe to the Azure IoT Hub topic. The function log will show all received events. Also,  the following testers can help you for end-to-end eventing test:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester

Comment: Thanks Roman. I connected an EventGridTrigger function, and this worked as expected. I then noticed that the original Queue subscription also began to work properly at exactly the same time the Function was connected! I then removed the Function and for now it seems like the Queue is still working.